# ClassFormatError Exception after adding javaee-web-api dependency

Tags: hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven

i want to use **EL 2.2** with **tomcat 7**
so i added the following dependency in my pom file:

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
```

but after i added it i am getting the following exception with hibernate:

```
ERROR [main] (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:490) - Destroy method on bean with name 'dataSource' threw an exception
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/TransactionRequiredException
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:166)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:487)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:431)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:433)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:84)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:280)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:62)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:140)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1009)
```

everything was working fine before i added this dependency, i think that it's conflicting with other dependencies, maybe i don't know, what do you think guys ?

Comment: I have no idea about the Maven part, but -as said before on one of your previous questions- Tomcat isn't a Java EE web profile compliant container. It's just a basic JSP/Servlet container. You've got to declare the individual JSP/Servlet dependencies instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BalusC noted - Tomcat is not web-profile compliant. So you can't just have `provided` scope for that.

You can check the recently released [TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/apache-tomee.html), which is a web-profile compliant container, and uses tomcat.

The exception in your case seems to be related to JPA - make sure your JPA dependencies are OK (for example make sure you don't have both 1.0 and 2.0 on the classpath). And another thing - for using EL you don't need to add a dependency. It is included in Tomcat.

Comment: Exception is not too directly connected to JPA, especially not to the versions. This exception comes also if you use something else that comes via javaee-web-api artifact. "Implementations" in javaee-web-api artifact are not really implementations, they miss body of the methods. Then result is this exception when trying to execute such method.

Comment: it is most likely related to the JPA exception class - it is a completely normal exception class. Only interfaces "miss body of the methods".

Comment: In normal cases also native and abstract methods tend to miss body. This implementation is not "completely normal". Just see the byte code for example in the constructor of javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException (one via this dependency of course, not some other implementation) and you will understand. I think "Absent Code attribute in method that ..." describes quite well to what you will see

Comment: can you point me to a reference that states that the JPA api classes (as well as other API and SPIs) have some custom bytecode that cannot be achieved by just compiling the sources?

Comment: I do not have such a reference and also no source code and no information about how it was compiled. If you have, I am interested to have it as well. Now when we have lack of references and sources, we can check result instead (because in the end that matters). If you don't want to check it by yourself, take a look to this: http://www.maunu.org/show/differences_PersistenceException.txt. You will find out that difference in those two matters in runtime.

Comment: Also there is not any kind of return instructions in any class files found from http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar file.
I hope that tells something about how usable these classes are runtime. You can read other experiences with this kind of library from http://svetzal.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/java-ee-6-untestable/
 and http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-download-j2ee-api-javaee-jar-from-maven/ or simply try it by yourself, to end up to same conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

What it comes to the question should you do this with Tomcat, just check comment from BalusC.

Reason why you see this stacktrace is that what you get with javaee-web-api dependency is kind of skeleton you can compile against (just public interface). There is not any real implementation whatsoever behind. This is how for example class you try to use looks via
*javap -c TransactionRequiredException*

```
Compiled from "TransactionRequiredException.java"
public class javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException extends javax.persistence.PersistenceException{
public javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException();

public javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException(java.lang.String);

}
```

Also there is not any kind of return instruction in any class found from http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar file.
You can read other experiments with this kind of library from

- http://svetzal.wordpress.com/2009/12/26/java-ee-6-untestable/ and
- http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-download-j2ee-api-javaee-jar-from-maven/

Calling any method or constructor for these classes will fail. That means that you should probably never use runtime anything that comes from this dependency.

- not for unit tests
- not for some Hibernate generation
- etc.

Before you used some real implementation of javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException during your unit tests, now it is empty shell from new dependency.